# Azure Devops - Is it possible to prevent copying or cloning a work item

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I would like the ability to prevent users from copying existing work items.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Would you mind sharing  why you want to prevent copying or cloning a work item?

Comment: you want to copy or clone a work item from Azure DevOps? or you want know or get notification for user cloning (downloading or exporting ) a work item

Comment: @TomSun We've customized Devops to fit the need of the business here.  We use custom fields for release planning, client tracking, etc.  When our analysts copy a work item, it also copies all of those fields.  Preventing copying would help us keep our releases and client information better organized.

Comment: @SanthakumarMunuswamy I want to prevent it all together.  I would like to remove the option to copy/clone a work item.

Comment: @TimSouthard did you ever find a way to do this?  We have the same need...

Comment: @Dave unfortunately no